# Question words "what" , "how" and Preposition + what "

Tags: questions

**Water clock was made of the container.**

If I change this sentence into question, which of the following is suitable?

> 1.How was the water clock made?
>
> 2.What was the water clock made of?
>
> 3.Of what was the water clock made of?

Comment: Your starting sentence isn't syntactically valid. At the very least, it would need to be ***The** water clock was made of the container*, but this isn't something a native speaker would ever say anyway, and to be honest, I have no idea what you intend it to *mean*. Note that asking ***how*** something was made is usually a completely different question to asking ***what** it was made **of***.

Comment: To elaborate on FF's comment, **made of** generally refers to the material, for example if the container was plastic you would say **made of plastic**. If you want to say that you used a container to make the water clock, you would say **made from**, or maybe **made from**.

Comment: @JavaLatte Also: "made out of", which, even more strongly than "made from" (which could be made using only part of something), suggests that the container itself was made into a water clock.

Comment: @LukeSawczak: oops: the second **made from** in my comment should have been **made out of**

Comment: @JavaLatte Ah, that makes more sense :)

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 doesn't convey your intended meaning. It means *What is the process of making the water clock?*.

Option 3 has duplicate "of"s, one at the beginning and one at the end of the sentence. Option 2 and the sentence below are correct:

> Of what was the water clock made?